# How to add box-shadow to a svg path circle shape

Tags: html, css

I have this problem, where I need to add box-shadow to a circle, but it seems it is not possible.

Why does it not work or how could I add circle shadow to the `</circle>` element in SVG path to have the glow effect with current specifications?

```css
/*
circle {
  fill: red; <-- works
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px red; <-- does not work
}
*/
```

```html
<svg width="450" height="450">
   <path id="motionPath"
   d="M 50 200 L 400 200 "
 stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
 <circle class="circle" r=5 fill=#45b6fe z-index=55>
             <animateMotion dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                 <mpath href="#motionPath" />
             </animateMotion>
         </circle>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a box-shadow, you will need to work on feGaussianBlur attribute. Below is the code for you and it generates beautiful box-shadow. You can check the output for the same

**Note:** To see the shadow properly, I have increased the dimension of circle. You can keep as per your requirement.

```html
<svg width="450" height="450">

<defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="-40%" y="-40%" width="180%" height="180%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="8"/> 
      <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feOffset dx="-5" dy="-5" result="offsetblur"/>
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
   <path id="motionPath"
   d="M 50 200 L 400 200 "
 stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
  
 <circle class="circle" r=10 fill=#45b6fe z-index=55 style="filter: url(#f1);">
  
             <animateMotion dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                 <mpath href="#motionPath" />
             </animateMotion>
         </circle>
         
      </svg>
```

**UPDATE:**
As per your requirement, I have added desired background color to the box shadow.

```html
<svg width="450" height="450">

    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="-40%" y="-30%" width="180%" height="180%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
        <feColorMatrix result="offsetblur" in="offOut" type="matrix"/>
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="10" /> 
         <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="10" result="blur"/>
<feOffset in="blur" dx="5" dy="5" result="offsetBlur" stdDeviation="1.7"/>
<feFlood flood-color="red" flood-opacity="5" result="offsetColor"/>
<feComposite in="offsetColor" in2="offsetBlur" operator="in" result="offsetBlur"/>
          <feMerge> 
            <feMergeNode/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
          </feMerge>
        </filter>
      </defs>
       <path id="motionPath"
       d="M 50 200 L 400 200 "
     stroke="black" fill="transparent" />
      
     <circle class="circle"  r=10 fill=white  z-index=55 style="filter: url(#f1);">
      
                 <animateMotion dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto">
                     <mpath href="#motionPath" />
                 </animateMotion>
             </circle>
             
          </svg>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help. The code functions, but I mostly need the box-shadow effect to be bigger than it is at the moment and with a coloured version. Mostly the need is a glow as in this example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/developingm/v5rk0j49/5/

Answer (score -1):

so I have this in one of my sites and it works fine for me

```
.booking-view-tariff-circle > img {
border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000;
display: block;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
object-fit: cover;
position: relative;
left: -45px;
top: -78px;
box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
```

Comment: This applies a shadow to the `img` box, not the svg element.