# How can I add a specific box shadow to my svg?

Tags: css, svg

So I know there is a question similar to this: [How to add box-shadow to a svg path circle shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658865/how-to-add-box-shadow-to-a-svg-path-circle-shape) but I am having trouble understanding how they transitioned the box shadow characteristics to the svg drop shadow characteristics. (Especially as SVG Drop shadows don't have the concept of a spread radius.)

I am trying to get this exact box shadow: box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(18, 103, 17, 0.15);

And I currently have:

```html
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="25" />
      <feOffset dx="0" dy="10" result="offsetblur" />
      <feOffset dx="-10" dy="0" result="offsetblur" />
      <feFlood flood-color="rgba(18, 103, 17, 0.15)" flood-opacity="1" />
      <feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode />
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="112.53" cy="112.53" r="87" fill="none" stroke="#74C947" stroke-width="25.53" style="filter: url(#drop-shadow);"></circle>
</svg>
```

Also if I can just use box-shadow css on the svg circle I'm happy to do so, but that doesn't seem to be an option (it only allows drop shadows).

Comment: Where is `JavaScript` here

Comment: @SusobhanDas sorry that's fair I'll remove it. I am using this in js code so my brain just auto added it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the svg and define the shadow in the class.

```
<svg class='svg-shadow'>...</svg>

.svg-shadow {
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #000;
}
```

Comment: Hmm that puts a shadow around the box behind the circle? as it covers the whole "body" or whatever of the svg

Comment: @Nerl Did you try adding a border-radius?

Comment: Ah so part of the issue is I do have other stuff going on in the SVG, making it so I can't just extract the circle (that would get messy). This is just the only part that I want a shadow on. I'd need to be able to just pick out the circle and only add a box shadow to it.

Answer (score 0):

In the specification for [box shadow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#shadow-blur) it says...

> ...the image that would be generated by applying to the shadow a Gaussian blur with a standard deviation equal to half the blur radius

So if you want to create a drop shadow in SVG you need to divide the box shadow blur radius (in your case 25px) by two and therefore you want stdDeviation="12.5"

Note that you can simplify your code.

1. SVG actually has a feDropShadow element so you could just use that

```html
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow">
      <feDropShadow stdDeviation="12.5" dx="10" dy="-10" flood-color="rgba(18, 103, 17, 0.15)" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="112.53" cy="112.53" r="87" fill="none" stroke="#74C947" stroke-width="25.53" style="filter: url(#drop-shadow);"></circle>
</svg>
```

2. but there's an even easier way using the canned drop-shadow filter i.e.

```html
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <circle cx="112.53" cy="112.53" r="87" fill="none" stroke="#74C947" stroke-width="25.53" style="filter: drop-shadow(10px -10px 12.5px rgba(18, 103, 17, 0.15))"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Um would it actually be more like "drop-shadow(0px, 10px, 12.5px, rgba(18, 103, 17, 0.15)" though? I know I was using some weird 10px -10px fields  but that was just from looking at some examples

Comment: Well you oddly have two feOffset elements in your question so up to you.

Comment: Hmm that was just me attempting stuff from following examples, I was really just trying to do box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px 0px rgba(18, 103, 17, 0.15); So I guess you were saying that yours is the same as that as you halved the 25px and the 0px spread radius isn't needed?